# using () or [] an a correct order for a long mathematics expression

Tags: equations, symbols

I have a very long mathematics expression:

```
x=\frac{1}{32} (2 \cos (t (J-3))+2 \cos (2 t (J-1))+12 \cos (t) \cos (t J)+2 \cos (2 t (J+1))+2 \cos (t (J+3))+4 \cos (2 t)+\cos (4 t)+7)
```

I do not know how and where must I use `()`, `\Big(\Big)`, `\{\}`, `\[\]` and so on in a correct order.

Can one say me where must I use above symbols?

Comment: Sorry, what *is* the question? Are you asking how the math should be written oder how to use the symbols?

Comment: What I would normally do is to put ( ) innermost, then [ ], and after that { }, so that you'd have something like `\Bigl\{ \bigl[  ( x ) \bigr] \Bigr\}`

Comment: I thought that parentheses and brackets in math had different meanings, therefore you can't use them in a (random) order. The same applies in text: square brackets [] can be used as in inner set of parentheses (). In editing classical texts square brackets [] normally mark editorial restorations, angle  brackets <> mark editorial insertions, and braces {} mark deletions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two versions, preferring the first one. Using

```
\cos \bigl(t (J-3)\bigr)
```

makes the formula part clearer. The parenthesis at the beginning has obviously to be at least `\big`, but I find that `\Big` is too large and not really necessary.

Keep fences as small as possible, without sacrificing to clarity.

By the way, this formula *must* be in a display.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
x=\frac{1}{32}\bigl(
 & 2 \cos \bigl(t (J-3)\bigr)
  +2 \cos \bigl(2 t (J-1)\bigr)
  +12 \cos (t) \cos (t J)
 \\
 &+2 \cos \bigl(2 t (J+1)\bigr)
  +2 \cos \bigl(t (J+3)\bigr)
  +4 \cos (2 t)+\cos (4 t)+7
  \bigr)\end{split}
\]

\[
\begin{split}
x=\frac{1}{32}\Bigl(
 & 2 \cos \bigl(t (J-3)\bigr)
  +2 \cos \bigl(2 t (J-1)\bigr)
  +12 \cos (t) \cos (t J)
 \\
 &+2 \cos \bigl(2 t (J+1)\bigr)
  +2 \cos \bigl(t (J+3)\bigr)
  +4 \cos (2 t)+\cos (4 t)+7
  \Bigr)\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]